# How to define a function with a parameter such that $\int_0^n f_n(x)dx = \int_0^m f_m(x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, functions

So, $f_n(x): R \to R$ is a function such that for any integer $n > 1$ and any real $v > 1$

1. $f_n(0) = v$
2. $f_n(n) = 1$
3. $f_n(x) > 0$ for $0 \leq x \leq n$
4. $f_n(x)$ is continuous and differentiable on $0 \leq x \leq n$
5. For any arbitrary integers $n$ and $m$ such that $n > 1$ and $m > 1$ the following is true: $\int_0^n f_n(x)dx = \int_0^m f_m(x)dx$

Finding a function that satisfies 1-4 is a fairly simple task. E.g. $f_n(x) = v^{1-\frac{x}{n}}$, or $f_n(x) = (1 - v) \frac{\log{x+1}}{\log{n + 1}} + v$, or even $f_n(x) = v + (1 - v)\frac{x}{n}$. The real problem comes with restriction 5. I spent all day trying different families of functions, but no matter what I try, it just doesn't work.

So, the questions are

1. Is it even possible to define $f_n(x)$?
2. If it is, what would the definition be?
3. If it is not possible to define, why?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets say that $\int_0^n f_n(x)\, dx = 1$, and lets try to $f_n(x) = g_n(x) + c_n\cdot h_n(x)$ where
$$g_n(0) = v,\ g_n(n) = 1,\ g_n(x) > 0,\ \int_0^n g_n(x)\, dx < 1$$
$$h_n(0) = h_n(n) = 0,\ h_n(x) \geq 0,\ \int_0^n h_n(x)\, dx > 0$$ If we can find such $g_n$ and $h_n$, setting $c_n = \frac{1 - \int_0^n g_n(x)\, dx}{\int_0^n h_n(x)\, dx}$ will give us necessary result.

Finding $h_n(x)$ is simple, for example $h_n(x) = x \cdot (n - x)$ works.

To find $g_n$, we want something that is large in $0$ and $n$, but very small between. For example, let $g_n(x) = \frac{1}{n^{p_n}} x^{p_n} + \frac{v}{n^{p_n}} (n - x)^{p_n}$
Then we have
$$g_n(0) = v$$
$$g_n(n) = 1$$
$$\int_0^n g_n(x)\, dx = \frac{n (1 + v)}{p_n + 1}$$

Thus, taking $p_n > n(1 + v)$, we get all necessary properties.

Comment: [+1] Please, have a look at my proposal.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to know Bézier curves, or more exactly rational Bézier curves, here is another solution.

Consider points $A=(0,v), \ B=(0,0), \ C=(n,0), \ D=(n,1) \tag{1}$

The ordinary cubic Bezier curve with endpoints $A,D$ and "pilot points" $B,C$ with parametric equations :

$$\pmatrix{x\\y}=\underbrace{\color{red}{1 (1-t)^3}}_{w_1} \pmatrix{0\\v}+\underbrace{\color{red}{3 t(1-t)^2}}_{w_2} \pmatrix{0\\0}+\underbrace{\color{red}{3 t^2 (1-t)}}_{w_3}  \pmatrix{n\\0}+\underbrace{\color{red}{1 t^3}}_{w_4} \pmatrix{n\\1}\tag{2}$$

has the desired shape due to classical properties (the fact that the curve is inside the convex hull of $A,B,C,D$, moreover that the parametric equations (2) can be turned into a cartesian equation $y=f(x)$,... ). See figure below.

[image]

Let $S_n$ be the area under the curve.

There is no reason that the different $S_n$ are the same.

In order to fulfill this condition, it suffices to place give to $B$ and $C$ a stronger weight in order to "attract" the curve towards line segment $BC$ in such a way that the $S_n$ are all the same (equal to $S_1$ for example).

Here is how, by multiplying the weights $w_2,w_3$ by a suitable same constant factor $f_n$ specific to value $n$. Just replace in (2),

- $w_1$ by $w_1/W$.
- $w_2,w_3$ by $f_nw_2/W, f_nw_2/W$ resp.
- $w_4$ by $w_4/W$.

where $W$, the total weight is : $W:=w_1+f_n(w_2+w_3)+w_4$ (reminder : $W$, as the $w_k$, is a function of variable $t$).

(one obtains in this way a "rational Bezier curve").

Remark 1: I have answered about the possibility issue : the answer is therefore "yes". But it remains to "tune" the good factor $f_n$. A more handy way would be to consider using spline functions, or more exactly NURBS, instead of Bézier or rational Bézier curves.

Remark 2 : instead of (1), one should take :

$$A=(0,v), \ B=(\varepsilon,0), \ C=(n-\epsilon,0), \ D=(n,1)$$

for a small $\epsilon$ in order that the curve is differentiable at endpoints $A,D$ (otherwise, the tangents in $A$ and $D$ are vertical...)

Comment: Just added a graphical representation.